# c# EF, Добавление новой записи в промежуточную таблицу m2m

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[image: er]

[image: diagram]

Как программно добавить новую запись в таблицу Records?

Comment: С какими данными?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну например вот так:

```
var course = ctx.Course.First();
var clients = ctx.Clients.Where(<cond>).ToList();
course.Clients = clients;
ctx.SaveChanges();`
```